# Selenium C# cannot find any element on page by Xpath, Id, name

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2012, xpath

I am quite new to Selenium and Visual Studio. I have created a test case to simply login to a web page and check for an element on the page having logged in. The login is fine and I get to the next page however I cannot find any element on the next page via any method such as XPath, Id or name. I get the following kinds of errors...

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='lblApplicationVersion']"}

I've also added some different waits such as...

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.XPath("//*[@id='lblApplicationVersion']"))));
```

...but this just waits for the full duration even though the page has definitely loaded.

The elements html from chrome is as follows...

```html
<html>

<head>...</head>
<frameset border="0" framespacing="0" rows="100,89%" frameborder="0">
  <frame name="ob_frm_header" src="header.aspx" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
    #document
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>...</head>

    <body>
      <form method="post" action="./header.aspx" id="Form1">
        <div class="aspNetHidden">...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          ...
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          ...
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          ...
        </script>
        <div id="header">
          <div id="header_left">
            <a id="OEMLogoLink" href="https://observatory.spikescavell.net/" target="_parent">...</a>
            <div id="application_version" class="statuspanel_application_version">
              <span id="lblApplicationVersion">v4.3.4</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="MainMenu1" onresize="MainMenuControls.MainMenuStrip.prototype.sizeChanged($get('MainMenu1'));" style="overflow: hidden; width: 1644px;" menuname="Observatory_Main" submenuleftoffset="201" submenuframe="ob_frm_main" submenuid="SubMenu1">
          </div>
          <div id="statuspanel">...</div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </body>

    </html>
  </frame>
  <frameset id="frmset_ob_menu_main" cols="201,81%" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
    <noframes>...</noframes>
  </frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: As is usually the case I think I've found the answer as soon as I've posted this! Looks like I need to switch the driver to the frame first i.e... driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame name);

Comment: Yes, this is the problem, frame is separate html document

Answer (score 1):

*It is good to hear you that, you have already found the solution, but you should share it as an answer that's why other users which have same problem could understand better that what is the actual problem.*

So for this purpose I'm writing here the solution of your problem.

Actually `frame` or `iframe` is the separate `HTML` document, so you have to switch this `frame` or `iframe` to set the current document before going to find element inside a `frame` or `iframe` as below :-

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("ob_frm_header"));

IWebElement element= wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("lblApplicationVersion")));
```

Or, if there is no need to implement `WebDriverWait`, it can be simply achieve as below :-

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ob_frm_header"); 
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.id("lblApplicationVersion"));
```

Comment: How to do this if the iframe does not have a name